# How to change how WYSIYG styles things?

Tags: 7, wysiwyg, theming

Instead of using HTML underline tags, I want the WYSIWYG editor (CKEditor) to wrap a span around the highlighted text. Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure see this great blog post titled [WYSIWYG Module + CKEditor: Taming the Beast](http://fuseinteractive.ca/blog/wysiwyg-module-ckeditor-taming-beast) by Fuse Interactive. I am not affiliated with the company nor the author of it -- it's simply a great resource.

Linked in those blog comments is a link to the [CKEditor Configuration Options documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration), which is what you'll end up altering to make this happen.

In the blog post they supply their own config settings for the editor in javascript. I believe you can set all these values in `hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter`, the settings for the Styles look like:

```
  { name : 'Float Right', element : 'div', attributes : { 'style' : 'float:right;' } },
    { name : 'Float Left', element : 'div', attributes : { 'style' : 'float:left;' } },
```

Where this defines a style called `Float Right` that wraps the selected text in a `div` with some inline styling. I believe you can easily assign classes instead of inline styles as well.

This should be a huge jumping off point for you to figure it all out. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/full_html/edit and select "Font Style" then go to the bottom of the page to the "CSS" tab and add Span=span in the "CSS classes" box.

You should now see "Span" in the styles select box on your content edit page.

If you want to give the span a style add Span name=span.name into the "CSS classes" box